# Pass function value to Jquery function call back

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a script that loads different content based on the previously clicked links. (For an Android app). I'm having problems getting data to pass to my call back function.

```
function load_current_div(id, refer){
    $('#current-div').hide(function(){
        $('#current-div').html('');
        $('#current-div').load('content/'+id+'.html', function(){
            alert(id);
        });
    });
    $('#current-div').show();
}
```

I cannot get the id to contain a value when alerted.

Comment: Seems ok, is this the whole code or is there more to it?  Is the callback function fired at all?

Comment: You might be right. Looks like the callback function is not firing. I've never had this issue before.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried creating a local variable to avoid the id being overwritten by something else ?

```
function load_current_div(id, refer){
    $('#current-div').hide(function(){
        var local_id = id;
        $('#current-div').html('');
        $('#current-div').load('content/'+local_id+'.html', function(){
            alert(local_id);
        });
    });
    $('#current-div').show();
}
```

Comment: I tried that. But no I am unsure if the call back is actually working. The pages load fine and then nothing else happens.

Comment: @Tim, use firebug to see what the ajax call returns .. (if it does..)